# Remove text to the right of a character in JS

Tags: javascript

I am using JS to remove/replace characters from a Page Title to show the `slug/url` as

```
function convertToSlug(Text){
    return Text
      .toString()
      .trim()
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
      .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, "")
      .replace(/\-\-+/g, "-")
      .replace(/^-+/, "")
      .replace(/-+$/, "");
  }
```

This will convert a page title of `This is a page title | Company Name` to `this-is-a-page-title-company-name` but how can I remove all text to the right of the `|` so that the returned slug is `this-is-a-page-title`?

Please note that the company name will change and just removing the whole part of `| Company Name` isn't sufficient. I need it to apply to any version of the title to the right of `|`.

Comment: Try `return str.split('|')[0].trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g, '').toLowerCase();`

Comment: You could just use `Text = Text.substr(0, Text.indexOf("|"));` and then your regex after that.

Comment: @Archer - Beat me to it! ;o)

Comment: @Archer. Got me part way there. Although, now if my title was ` Make Mondays Better | Disc Beta` I get a return of ` make-mondays-better-d`

Comment: Put this in the browser console... `"Make Mondays Better | Disc Beta".substr(0, "Make Mondays Better | Disc Beta".indexOf("|"))` I get `Make Mondays Better ` (with a space, but the regex will clear that)

Comment: @Archer. You are correct - it was something else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries - you've got enough answers here to help you out now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the pipe symbol (`|`), and everything after it with an empty string:

```js
function convertToSlug(Text){
    return Text
      .replace(/\|.*/, '')
      .trim()
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  }
  
console.log(convertToSlug('This  is a page    title | Company Name'));
```

Comment: `.toString()` can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that you are using | char as seperator, you can use following:

```
function convertToSlug(Text){
    return Text
     .split('|')[0]
     .trim()
     .toLowerCase()
     .replace(/\s/g,"-");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but could be useful to someone else.

```
<input type="text" id="txtInput" />
<input type="button" onclick="return convertToSlug();" value="Remove text to the right of a character in JS
">
<script>
function convertToSlug(){
    var Text = document.getElementById("txtInput");
    var purgeCharPosition = Text.indexOf("|");
    return Text
      .toString()
      .trim()
      .substr(purgeCharPosition)
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
      .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, "")
      .replace(/\-\-+/g, "-")
      .replace(/^-+/, "")
      .replace(/-+$/, "");
}
</script>
```